# Loop in Columns and Rows to find and copy values

Tags: excel, vba, loops, filter

I need to create a multi loop for the table below in the image.

The loop needs to find and copy all the rows where (for instance):
If Bat=1 and Bet=1 and Bit=F and Bot = 1 and But=1, copy the row to another sheet.

It needs to be dynamic because the data changes every day, and I will need to create one loop for each "categorical" row, for instance: 1-1-F-1-1, 1-1-J-1-1 and so on.

I searched in a lot of topics here.

I tried this:

```vb
Option Explicit
    
Sub Test()
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("base")
    Dim ARow As Long, BRow As Long, CRow As Long, DRow As Long, ERow As Long, MyCellA As Range, MyCellB As Range, MyCellC As Range, MyCellD As Range, MyCellE As Range, Names As String
    ARow = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
    BRow = ws.Range("B" & ws.Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
    CRow = ws.Range("C" & ws.Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
    DRow = ws.Range("D" & ws.Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
    ERow = ws.Range("E" & ws.Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
    
    For Each MyCellA In ws.Range("A2:A" & ARow)
        For Each MyCellB In ws.Range("B2:B" & BRow)
            For Each MyCellC In ws.Range("C2:C" & CRow)
                For Each MyCellD In ws.Range("D2:D" & DRow)
                    For Each MyCellE In ws.Range("E2:E" & ERow)
                            If MyCellA = 2 And MyCellB = 3 And MyCellC = "F" And MyCellD = 1 And MyCellE = 1 Then
                                MsgBox "Category 1 Achieved!"
                            End If
                    Next MyCellE
                Next MyCellD
            Next MyCellC
        Next MyCellB
    Next MyCellA
    
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: You only need a single loop here - take each row in turn and run your checks on that row.

Comment: Hey Tim, good night! Thanks for your help, buddy. But I don't see how a single loop would solve this. Since I need to validade 5 conditions in 5 different columns for each row to create a category, for instance, 1-1-J-1-1 (I'll copy all rows with this pattern to another sheet later), how could I do this with a single loop? Could you, please, exemplify for me? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need a single loop here - take each row in turn and run your checks on that row.

Like this:

```vb
Sub Test()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim ARow As Long, rw As Long
    
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("base")
    ARow = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    
    For Each rw In ws.Range("A2:E" & ARow).Rows
        
        'Test the relevant cells on the row for the required values
        If rw.Cells(1).Value = 2 Then
            If rw.Cells(2).Value = 3 Then
                If rw.Cells(3).Value = "F" Then
                    If rw.Cells(4).Value = 1 Then
                        If rw.Cells(5).Value = 1 Then
                            MsgBox "Category 1 Achieved!"
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End If
           
    Next rw

End Sub
```

Note if you just `AND` all the check together it will be noticeably slower, since all 5 cells need to be read even though the first one may have failed your criteria.

Comment: Woooow, thanks soooo much, Tim, it worked perfectly!! You saved me =D Have a great day!

Comment: ++ nicely done. I was wondering why not join all the `Ifs` using `And`?